# Ошибка при чтении csv файла

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv

```
import csv

def parseFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        file = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
        for row in file:
            print row

def main():
    parseFile('1.csv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

При чтении файла возникает ошибка _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte.

С чем это может быть связано?

Файл csv имеет вид:

```
"347336"    "236908"    "502367"    "890236"    
"628573"    "2560726"   "34625" "2625622"   
"562225"    "2564562"   "624564536" "56256463646"
```

Разделитель - табуляция

Comment: А из чего следует, что в файле действительно нет нулевых байт? Hex-dump смотрели?

Comment: А может вам unicode-csv подсунули.

Comment: Может [это SO read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7) или [это github](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) поможет.

Comment: *"line contains NULL byte."* говорит что нулевой байт в файле. В какой кодировке входной файл? Покажите `print repr(open("1.csv", "rb").read())`

Comment: Кодировка файла UCS-2